# Confusion in differential forms Spivak

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-fields

On page 90 of Spivak's Calculus on manifolds

> 4-8 Theorem (3) $f^*(g.w)=(g\circ f)\cdot f^*w   $.

Here I assume $g $ is a function $$f^*(g.w)(p)(v_p)=(g.w)(f(p))(f_*v)=g(f(p))(f_*v)\cdot w(f(p))(f_*v)=(g \circ f_*)(f^*w)  $$ 
What is wrong with my calculation?
Also, I want clarity on following questions
1) Is $w$ which is a $k-form$ a vector field ?
2)What sort of function is $g$ i.e. from where to where ?

Comment: You missed the last equality. It should be $(g \circ f)(p) (f^* w)(p)$. $w$ and $g$ is a form and a function (resp.) on the codomain of $f$

Answer (score 1):

$$(g\cdot \omega)(f(p))(f_*(v_1),\ldots,f_*(v_k)) = g(f(p))\omega(f(p))(f_*(v_1),\ldots,f_*(v_k)) = ((g \circ f) \cdot f^*\omega)(p)(v_1,\ldots,v_k).$$

1) No, a $k$-form is not a vector field. At each point, a $k$-form converts $k$ tangent vectors into a real number.

2) Here $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ and $g:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R$, in order for $g \cdot \omega$ to make sense.

Comment: Why not the way I have written? By $g(f(p))(f_* v)$ we mean $g(f_* v)$ at $f(p)$ right?

Comment: @mathemather You have written $g(f(p))(f_*v)$, but that doesn't mean anything. $g$ is a function, so $g(f(p))$ is a real number. You can't evaluate that at a tangent vector.

Comment: So only forms can be evaluated at tangent vectors right?

Comment: In this setting, yes. Multiplication of a $k$-form $\omega$ by a function $g$ yields a $k$-form $g\cdot \omega$ via the rule $(g\cdot \omega)(p)(v_1,\ldots,v_k) = g(p) \cdot \omega(p)(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$.